# Laravel BD::rollBack Don't work in my code

Tags: database, laravel

I made the code below in order to validate a transaction in which the balance and history would be saved in the database or none of them. However, when I run the code and check the database I see that the balance is still being inserted into the bank instead of being canceled. What could be the mistake?

Below is the method code of my balance model responsible for the operation

```
public function deposit(float $value) : Array {

        DB::beginTransaction();

        $totalBefore = null;
        // $totalBefore = $this->amount ? $this->amount : 0;
        $this->amount += number_format($value, 2, ".", '');
        $deposit = $this->save();

        $historic = auth()->user()->historics()->create([
            'type'          => 'I', 
            'amount'        => $value, 
            'total_before'  => $totalBefore, 
            'total_after'   => $this->amount, 
            'date'          => date('Ymd'),
        ]);

        if ($deposit && $historic) {
            DB::commit();

            return [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Sucesso ao recarregar!'
            ];
        }

        else {
            DB::rollBack();

            return [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Falha ao recarregar!'
            ];
        }     
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? If one of the value is saved the other one should be present as well. Is not what is happening?

Comment: The problem is that I wanted to configure the code so that a search was dereferred if the values could not be entered or there were any types of errors. For example, if you could not enter a history, the balance would also no longer be saved. The balance is being received by the deposit in that case.

Answer (score 0):

When you use save() it is not getting rolled back by db::rollBack().

Comment: It *should*, though, shouldn't it?

Comment: But in this case, how is more efficient method for this operation? I want only update this balance (deposit) or create a new if this not exists.

Comment: Then use updateOrCreate method as explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent